# Determining coin mint year from a known sample based on elemental composition

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis

I wondered if you could help me with a stats question, please?

I have data on the metallic compositions (percentages of specific elements) of 30 coins, each minted in a different year from 1902 to 1967. I also have the composition of a coin minted in an unknown year which I would like to try and classify to a year of minting through comparison with the reference dataset.

How would I go about doing this?

I attempted discriminant analysis in SPSS using Coin Year (numeric; nominal) as the grouping variable and the percentages of each metal element (Cu, Sn, Zn, Pb, As, Zr, Ni, Nb, Co, W, Mn, Se) as the Independents, but received the error: “Warnings: There are 31 non-empty groups and 31.000 (31 unweighted) cases that are valid. Not enough weighted or unweighted cases. Execution of this command stops.” I suspect this is because there is only one set of values associated with each year, but I’m stuck on how to overcome this.

I thought about potentially using a Euclidean distance measure, but I’m not sure. Any advice?
Thanks so much!

Comment: If you have exactly one coin for each year and you want to predict the year of an unknown coin based on the other attributes then a simple distance measure as you proposed is probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: You have more than 30 years between 1902 and 1967. Can your unknown coin be from any of those years, even if that year was not one of those 30?

Comment: In theory yes, but some years can be excluded as being quite different in elemental composition. The problem I have is giving a strength to the conclusion. Like based on a distance meaure can I say the coin is most likely from x year/years. I was hoping to generate some sort of cluster like a PCA plot, but I do not think that is possible because you only have one coin per year. I then tried to group into decades, but that did not work either.

Comment: I would expect the mint itself to be at least as important as the year, especially if these are US coins, because the sources of the metals used in San Francisco, Denver, and Philadelphia likely varied.